# jQuery: on click add class and set a variable

Tags: jquery, if-statement

The idea is to change the class of a link to active while removing active from other links and to set a variable to a value depending on the link that is clicked. If "1" is clicked the variable firstNumber would be 1. This is for kind of a "validation" later on. The code is below, the class changing works if the "if else if..." part is removed, so something must be wrong with that part, just what?

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.numbers-1 a').click(function(){
        $('.numbers-1 a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        if ( $(this).hasClass('num-1') ) {
            var firstNumber = 1;
        } else if ( $(this).hasClass('num-2') ) {
            var firstNumber = 2;
        } else if ( $(this).hasClass('num-3') ) {
            var firstNumber = 3;
        } else ( $(this).hasClass('num-4') ) {
            var firstNumber = 4;
        };
    });
});
```

the html is here

```
<div class="numbers-1">
    <a class="num-1" href="#">1</a>
    <a class="num-2" href="#">2</a>
    <a class="num-3" href="#">3</a>
    <a class="num-4" href="#">4</a>
</div>
```

So, why is the if statement not working in the jquery?

Comment: A little tweak suggestion: you don't need this whole block, if you use jquery's `$(this.data("myvar")` function and `data-myvar="1"` tags on the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`else` was supposed to be an `else if` on your final statement I'm assuming as `else` doesn't take a conditional statement.

```
else if ( $(this).hasClass('num-4') ) {
   var firstNumber = 4;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/gxeUK/)

Comment: Well that was simple... Thanks! Come up with a simple way to check the selected numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to simplify your code. What about this ?

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.numbers-1 a').click(function(){
        $('.numbers-1 a').removeClass('active');

        var currentClass = $(this).attr('class');

        $(this).addClass('active');

        var firstNumber = parseInt(currentClass.split('-')[1]);
    });
});
```